# IBM Cloud - How to adjust speaking rate in Watson TTS using curl POST?

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson, ssml

I'm having issues trying to adjust the prosody speaking rate in IBM Watson's TTS Service using curl.
Here is the code I've tried, it does synthesize audio but just completely ignores the `--header "prosody rate: +50%" ^` line I inserted which was to be expected as I'm unsure how to make that happen and just improvised that.
Does anyone know how I could get it to work as intended? I want to speed it up by 50%, but I can't find anything in the docs to help me when it comes to this request format.

Thanks!

```html
curl -X POST -u "apikey:apikey" ^
--header "Content-Type: application/json" ^
--header "Accept: audio/wav" ^
--header "prosody rate: +50%" ^
--data "{\"text\":\"Adult capybaras are one meter long.\"}" ^
--output hello_world.wav ^
"URL/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_HenryV3Voice"
```

Comment: Did my answer below worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

`prosody` is an SSML option, so I would expect it to be used as tags around the text that you are synthesising.

```
--data "{\"text\":\"<prosody rate = \"fast\">Adult capybaras are one meter long.</prosody>\"}"
```

Comment: Throws HTTP 400 Bad request. this works instead `--data '{"text":"<prosody rate=\"fast\">Adult capybaras are one meter long.</prosody>"}'`. Check my complete answer below

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example with the `POST` call,

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{API_KEY}" \
--header "Accept: audio/wav" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"text": "<p><s><prosody rate=\"+50%\">This is the first sentence of the paragraph.</prosody></s><s>Here is another sentence.</s><s>Finally, this is the last sentence.</s></p>"}' \
--output result.wav \
"{URL}/v1/synthesize" -v
```

on a Windows command prompt(cmd),

Create a JSON file `input.json` with the below command

```
echo {"text": "<p><s><prosody rate='+50%'>This is the first sentence of the paragraph.</prosody></s><s>Here is another sentence.</s><s>Finally, this is the last sentence.</s></p>"} > input.json
```

and then cURL to see result.wav file

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{API_KEY}" ^
--header "Accept: audio/wav" ^
--header "Content-Type: application/json" ^
--data @input.json ^
--output result.wav ^
"{URL}/v1/synthesize" -v
```

For the sentence in your question, replace the JSON above with yours

```
{"text":"<prosody rate='fast'>Adult capybaras are one meter long.</prosody>"}
```

Here's some useful links I followed to create this code sample that will help you in understanding the SSML attributes. Also, check the limitations of `<prosody>` in the links below

- https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/text-to-speech?topic=text-to-speech-usingHTTP#usingHTTP
- https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/text-to-speech?topic=text-to-speech-elements#break_element
- https://text-to-speech-demo.ng.bluemix.net

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and sorry for answering so late, but it's generating an audio file that's actually an error code: when I open the generated file with notepad, I get this.
I can't figure out what's wrong.
    

    {
   "error": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)",
   "code": 400,
   "code_description": "Bad Request"
    }

Comment: I think it's due to the fact that I'm on Windows and ' doesn't work on Windows. How can I fix that?

Comment: In place of `\` in the command use `^` for new-line on Windows. Check my updated answer

Comment: Hi, I tried that and I have the same problem, I still get the same Error 400 Bad Request.
Weird, could it be due to bad escaping or maybe some formatting error?

Comment: Can you remove the caps the end, move everything into a single line for simplicity and try? I don’t have a Windows machine to try :(

Comment: @Bloggy Updated my answer with the new instructions that worked for me on Windows